# How to find the mismatched string between 2 comma separated columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, csv

How to find the mismatched string between 2 comma separated columns in oracle

String 1: Apple,Banana
String 2: Banana, Orange

I need to get the apple in result

Comment: This is poor database/table design.  A better exercise would be for you to normalize your data.  I also don't think this is a very good homework question.

Comment: Also, why only Apple? Orange is also a mismatch. (And arguably Banana might be as it's in a different position.)

Comment: My motive is to find the item mismatched in the first comma separated string. When I googled, I didn't get a direct answer. So posted my answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT RESULT, RESULT FROM (
SELECT LISTAGG(DATA,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DATA)RESULT FROM  (
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('APPLE,BANANA','[^' || ',' || ']+',1,LEVEL)DATA FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ('APPLE,BANANA') - LENGTH (REPLACE ('APPLE,BANANA', ',')) + 1
MINUS
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('BANANA,ORANGE','[^' || ',' || ']+',1,LEVEL)DATA FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ('BANANA,ORANGE') - LENGTH (REPLACE ('BANANA,ORANGE', ',')) + 1))

RESULT                         RESULT                        
------------------------------ ------------------------------
APPLE                          APPLE
```